# Qtimer not timing out QT, C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning C++ and using QT.
I have a small program in which I am trying to update the text of the PushButton every second. The label being current time. I have a timer that should time out every second, but seems like it never does. here's the code.

**Header File**

```
#ifndef _HELLOFORM_H
#define _HELLOFORM_H

#include "ui_HelloForm.h"

class HelloForm : public QDialog {
public:
    HelloForm();
    virtual ~HelloForm();
public slots:
    void textChanged(const QString& text);
    void updateCaption();
private:
    Ui::HelloForm widget;

};

#endif /* _HELLOFORM_H */
```

**CPP file**

```
#include "HelloForm.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QtGui/QPushButton>
#include <QTime>


HelloForm::HelloForm(){
    widget.setupUi(this);

    widget.pushButton->setText(QTime::currentTime().toString());
    widget.pushButton->setFont(QFont( "Times", 9, QFont::Bold ) );

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateCaption()));
    timer->start(1000);

    connect(widget.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()) );
    connect(widget.nameEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(textChanged(const QString&)));
}

HelloForm::~HelloForm() {
}

void HelloForm::textChanged(const QString& text) {
    if (0 < text.trimmed().length()) {
        widget.helloEdit->setText("Hello " + text.trimmed() + "!");
    } else {
        widget.helloEdit->clear();
    }
}
void HelloForm::updateCaption() {
    QString myVar;
    myVar = QTime::currentTime().toString();
    widget.pushButton->setText(myVar);


}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated... The PushButton's text never changes...

Comment: Now that you have thanked someone for an answer ... you should accept it so they get reputation (and you do as well).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't include the `Q_OBJECT` macro at the beginning of your class.  You need it if your class declares any signals or slots (at least, if you want them to work).  In fact, it's generally a good practice to include it in any class that is derived from QObject.

Modify your class declaration to look like this:

```
class HelloForm : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT;
public:
    // Actual code here.
};
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT